# Find the straight line from two plane vectors

Tags: vectors

Two planes have equations $x + 3y - 2z = 4$ and $2x +y +3z = 5$. The planes intersect in the straight line $l$.

Find a vector equation for the line $l$.

How can I do this type of question?

Comment: How have you done this type of question?

Comment: I have never done this type of question

Comment: Find two points where the planes intersect. From these two points you can form a line. Can you do the rest?

Comment: How do I find a point that intersects between two planes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\vec{l}(a,b,c)$.

Hence, $a+3b-2c=0$ and $2a+b+3c=0$, which gives $b=-\frac{7}{11}a$ and $c=-\frac{5}{11}a$.

Let $a=11$. Hence, $b=-7$ and $c=-5$ and $\vec{l}(11,-7,-5)$.

But for $z=0$ we get $x=\frac{11}{5}$ and $y=\frac{3}{5}$, which gets an answer:
$$\left\{\left(\frac{11}{5}+11t,\frac{3}{5}-7t,-5t\right)|t\in\mathbb R\right\}$$

Comment: Why are the equations = 0, and how do you go from those equations to get $b = \frac{-7}{11}a$ and $c = \frac{-5}{11}a$

Comment: @Riduan Gonzalez $\vec{n_1}(1,3,-2)\perp\vec{l}$ and $\vec{n_2}(2,1,3)\perp\vec{l}$, which gives $\vec{l}\vec{n_1}=\vec{l}\vec{n_2}=0$

Comment: And how do you get those b and c values?

Comment: @Riduan Gonzalez I can take all non-zero value of $a$. If $a=11$ then we'll get an integer coordinates.

Comment: Ok, I got it now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Method I:

Let $z=t$. Solve $\begin{cases} x+3y=2t+4 \\ 2x+y=5-3t \end{cases}$ for $x$ and $y$. Then you have $(x,y,z)=(at+b, ct+d,t)$ for some $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb{R}$. The vector equation is $\mathbf{r}=(a,c,1)t+(b,d,0)$.

Method II:

$(1,3,-2)\times (2,1,3)$ is a direction vector of the line. Take an arbitrary value of $z$ (say $0$) and solve for $x$, $y$ to obtain a point on the line.

Method III:

Take two arbitrary values of $z$ (say $0$ and $1$). Solve for $x$ and $y$ in each case to obtain two points on the line. The difference of the two points gives a direction vector of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Find the intersection:

$$\begin{cases}I\;\;&x+3y-2z=4\\{}\\II\;\;&2x+y+3z=5\end{cases}\implies II-2I:\;\;-5y+7z=-3\implies\color{red}{y=\frac75z+\frac35}$$

and substituting in $\;I\;$ :

$$x+\frac{21}5z+\frac95-2z=4\implies \color{red}{x=-\frac{11}5z+\frac{11}5}$$

and thus the line is

$$\left(\frac{11}5\,,\,\,\frac35\,,\,0\right)+t\left(-11,\,7,\,5\right)\;,\;\;t\in\Bbb R$$